# Upstart job to start, stop and restart other jobs

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

I have around between 3 and 8 upstart jobs in various Ubuntu boxes that I wish to easily start, stop or restart all together. It seems that upstart would make it easy to do that, but I'm not sure how.

Should I use dependencies to make a single dummy job that depends on all the others? One of my requirements is that I wish to still be able to stop some without them restarting because others are started. How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved by creating a dummy master job (/etc/init/master_job.conf):

```
description "master_job"

start on filesystem or runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
```

and the others start and stop on it (/etc/init/other_job.conf):

```
start on starting master_job
stop on stopping master_job
```